# Why do MKDIR and DIR still work when XCOPY doesn't?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-xp-sp3, system32

I recently encountered an error where XCOPY wouldn't work in a batch file returning:

> 'xcopy' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.

Several other commands (ie: HELP) returned the same error, which I discovered was due to where %SYSTEMROOT%\SYSTEM32 was defined in the path variable. It was burried in the middle, but moving it to the beginning fixed this issue.

I do not understand why other commands (ie: MKDIR in the same batch file) are still recognized when the other commands aren't. Are these defined elsewhere in the OS in a way that makes them always accessable?

Setup is Windows XP Professional 2002 SP3, 32-Bit running in Oracle VM VirtualBox.

Comment: xcopy is an actual executable (xcopy.exe) that resides in your system32 path.

Comment: My system32 folder is buried in the middle as well and all my commands work just fine.  Possible that you were editing the PATH variable incorrectly?

Comment: @Squashman, I had never edited the path directly. I had installed other programs which had modified the path and added their directories at the beginning. It's possible that all I needed was a computer restart, but simply copying the SYSTEMROOT paths to the beginning of the PATH variable worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MKDIR` and `DIR` are cmd.exe internal commands and are not separate executable files. [Here you can find](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-internal.html) the fill list of the internal commands:

> ASSOC, BREAK, CALL ,CD/CHDIR, CLS, COLOR, COPY, DATE, DEL, DIR, DPATH, ECHO, ENDLOCAL, ERASE, EXIT, FOR, FTYPE, GOTO, IF, KEYS, MD/MKDIR, MKLINK (vista and above), MOVE, PATH, PAUSE, POPD, PROMPT, PUSHD, REM, REN/RENAME, RD/RMDIR, SET, SETLOCAL, SHIFT, START, TIME, TITLE, TYPE, VER, VERIFY, VOL